# how can we run selenium through celery tasks on redis server

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, redis, celery, django-celery

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

it is showing this on celery terminal and tasks is stoped.

```
[2024-02-09 10:41:58,247: DEBUG/MainProcess] Selenium Manager binary found at: C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe
[2024-02-09 10:41:58,247: DEBUG/MainProcess] Executing process: C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --debug --output json
```

i need to solve this issue.
and i need to run selenium chrome web driver on celery tasks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.